# Need to access Magento 1.9.x website by way of IP

Tags: magento-1.9, admin-panel, access

We recently moved away from Magento but still have access to it on our private server by way of its internal IP address. How do I access the pages and admin panel referencing just the IP address.

When I access it using x.x.x.x/index.php/our_dashboard, it forwards to the new website (website.com/index.php/our_dashboard), which I don't want.

Thank you all in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest creating dedicated virtual hosts (Apache) / server blocks (Nginx) for your websites. That's the solution which solves the problem of having multiple websites sharing the same resources. Sure, this doesn't mean you will access the websites by IP, but will separate the requests.

If however you still want to use the IPs, then the solution is to move one of the website to another machine with a different IP.

---

**LE** since you are looking for using Magento by IP location, i would suggest you check https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/v2.3/stores/store-urls.html as they mention that you could use urls with IP addresses.

Comment: Thank you for that, Diana. I need to be able to refer to the old website only by its IP address, as Magento changes the references to the webpages to the domain name rather than the IP address. Is there a way to change the domain name to an IP address reference only in the code?

Comment: Check the update to my answer, maybe it helps.